# Deleted User Control still gives me a "Does not contain" error for a click event I didn't use

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

I have a User Control that I deleted because it displayed some weird problem.

It kept saying `does not contain a definition` for a `button click event` that I haven't even used, so I tried deleting said User Control but the problem still persisted. And I know it's that User Control because the `UserControl1.xaml` is its name and the error is pointing to that file.

My button's click event on the deleted User Control is named `playSubmitClick` while the error is saying that `UserControl1.xaml` does not contain a definition for `readSubmitClick`.

The `readSubmitClick` is a button click event on another UserControl of mine but not the `UserControl1.xaml`, my problem now is it keeps on saying that error despite me deleting the entire User Control.

I think my problem is similar to this person's problem: https://forums.asp.net/t/1329577.aspx?does+not+contain+a+definition+for+Button_Click+

He deleted and readded the buttons and the error kept persisting. He said something about adding some .dll at one point and I'm wondering what those are.

Comment: I'm really dumbfounded, my only solution at the moment is to just create a new project and copy/paste the codes.

Comment: How did you delete the Control?  Is it still visible in Project Explorer (with Show-All-Files selected)?  In Windows File explorer?  Also do a Ctrl+Shift+F for the filename.

Comment: Omg, you're right, I accidentally made a copy of the User Control and placed it in another folder. So that's where it was pointing at, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

In the error list window see the line number.

[image]

Go to this line number in your xaml and look for `readSubmitClick` and delete it.

Comment: That's what's confusing me, I already deleted the User Control it's pointing at and I'm not sure where its getting the Line. Out of curiosity though, I undid the delete and went to line '36', the supposed culprit, and it was a label and had no click event on it. I also tried deleting everything on the User Control and just leaving a blank grid but it still points to line '36' even if the entire line left on that xaml is only up to line 13.